# C# reference to MS Outlook in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, office-interop

I am developing an app in VScode and I am wondering if there are any ways I can reference the MS Outlook objects library, the aim is to be able to parse emails in Outlook. Do I have to download and reference the PIA library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to automate Outlook from a managed application and access the Outlook object model members you need to add a reference to the interop assembly. Typically interop libraries are installed with Office applications if .NET Programmability Support for Microsoft Office was selected in the installation wizard. See [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) for more information. Also you may find the [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) page in MSDN helpful.